# What programming patterns or strategy should I use to deal with small inconsistencies in data processing?

Tags: ruby, parsing, design-patterns, data-processing

In the ruby gem I am writing I have to take in as input certain known query parameters and massage them into a query string and then use that constructed (url) string as a rest endpoint to retrieve that data.

Now there are some weird inconsistencies in inputs coming in and I am forking my code to normalize inputs into a consistent output.

```
   def build_query(params, endpoint)
      limit      = Hash[limit:      params[:limit]   ||  0]
      skip       = Hash[skip:       params[:skip]    ||  0]
      asc        = Hash[asc:        params[:asc]     || ""]
      desc       = Hash[desc:       params[:desc]    || ""]

      query = [limit, skip, asc, desc].select { |hash| hash.values.none? { |val| val == '' || val == 0 } }
      encoded = query.map{ |q| q.to_query }.join("&")

      references = build_references(params[:include]) || ""

      query_string = references.empty? ? "#{endpoint}#{encoded}" : "#{endpoint}#{references}&#{encoded}"
    end
```

You will see above that the `references` piece of the `params` are not handled the same way as the rest of the parameters. There are more slightly inconsistent edge cases coming soon. And the only way I know how to deal with these is to keep forking my code inside this function. It's going to get messy soon!

So how should I now refactor this code? Where should I go from here to manage this complexity? Should I use collaborating objects (`ParamsBuilder` or `QueryManager`) and some kind of polymorphism strategy?

I would like to keep my code simple and functional as much as possible.

Comment: Do you have an example for params and endpoint, and what should be returned by the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plain = %i|limit skip asc desc| # plain values
built = { include: ->(input) { build_references(input) } } # procs

query = (plain | built).map do |p|
  case p
  when Symbol then params[p]
  when Array  then p.last.(params[p.first])
  end
end.reject(&:blank?).map(&:to_query).join("&")

[endpoint, query].join
```

Basically, you have two types of parameters: those you are to pass through as is (like `:limit`,) and those, you are to transform (like `:include`.)

Former are just passed through, latter are transformed using the list of lambdas specified in the very beginning of this snippet.

Since you were using `to_query` in the original question, I suggest you use `rails`, hence you have `blank?` method on hand and there is no need to explicitly check for empty strings and/or zeroes.

In the last step, we reject blanks and join everything with an ampersand.

Comment: So are you suggesting I separate each kind of parsing strategy into its own type expressed as a lambda? Then I pipe the results as an array into a query pipeline etc? Is that what is happening here?